# When I load two identical (confirmed by IntelliJ) JS scripts into my web app one produces different results than the other

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc, jsp, intellij-idea, tomcat9

TL;DR: IntelliJ confirms to different scripts are identical, but they produce different results when ran in the browser (using IntelliJ with Tomcat). Exact details below.

I am creating a web project using Spring MVC that allows me to play chess. I am using the [chess.js](https://github.com/jhlywa/chess.js) library and the [chessboard.js](https://github.com/oakmac/chessboardjs/) library.

According to the chess.js library `README`, it has a method`pgn()` that returns the moves of the game as a `string`. You can optionally pass in a `JSON` to set a max_length and a newline character so that there is a new line character after black moves. For example `game.pgn({ max_width: 5, newline_char: '<br />' })`.

Here's my problem. I made a script called `initgame.js` that instantiates a chess game using the libraries and attempted to use the example above so that the moves printed out would be formatted to print a new line after each turn.

It wasn't working as I had hoped. So I created another script `test_game.js` to experiment and when I got the behavior I wanted I copy and pasted the contents of `test_game.js` into `initgame.js`. Changed the `<script>` tag point to `initgame.js` again and it was ignoring the line breaks again. Used IntelliJ to compare the files and IntelliJ confirms that the files are indeed identical.

Now I am just dumbfounded. I tried rebuilding the project, cleaning the Artifacts, cleaning Maven. Nothing. I even closed out of IntelliJ and restarted. When I run the program with `test_game.js` it works as desired. When I run it with `initgame.js` it ignores the line breaks.

As a potential hint, this doesn't happen when I use Visual Studio and load it into the browser as an `.html` instead of a `.jsp` Any insight is appreciated! Code and screen shots of output are below as well as a screen shot IntelliJ comparing the files.

`initgame.js`

```
// NOTE: this example uses the chess.js library:
// https://github.com/jhlywa/chess.js

var board = null;
const game = new Chess()
var $status = $('#status');
var $fen = $('#fen');
var $pgn = $('#pgn');

function onDragStart (source, piece, position, orientation) {
    // do not pick up pieces if the game is over
    if (game.game_over()) return false;

    // only pick up pieces for the side to move
    if ((game.turn() === 'w' && piece.search(/^b/) !== -1) ||
        (game.turn() === 'b' && piece.search(/^w/) !== -1)) {
        return false
    }
}

function onDrop (source, target) {
    // see if the move is legal
    var move = game.move({
        from: source,
        to: target,
        promotion: 'q' // NOTE: always promote to a queen for example simplicity
    });

    // illegal move
    if (move === null) return 'snapback';

    updateStatus()
}

// update the board position after the piece snap
// for castling, en passant, pawn promotion
function onSnapEnd () {
    board.position(game.fen())
}

function updateStatus () {
    var status = '';

    var moveColor = 'White';
    if (game.turn() === 'b') {
        moveColor = 'Black'
    }

    // checkmate?
    if (game.in_checkmate()) {
        status = 'Game over, ' + moveColor + ' is in checkmate.'
    }

    // draw?
    else if (game.in_draw()) {
        status = 'Game over, drawn position'
    }

    // game still on
    else {
        status = moveColor + ' to move';

        // check?
        if (game.in_check()) {
            status += ', ' + moveColor + ' is in check'
        }
    }

    $status.html(status);
    $fen.html(game.fen());
    $pgn.html(game.pgn({ max_width: 5, newline_char: '<br />' }))
}

var config = {
    draggable: true,
    position: 'start',
    onDragStart: onDragStart,
    onDrop: onDrop,
    onSnapEnd: onSnapEnd
};
board = Chessboard('myBoard', config);

updateStatus();
```

`test_game.js`

```
// NOTE: this example uses the chess.js library:
// https://github.com/jhlywa/chess.js

var board = null;
const game = new Chess()
var $status = $('#status');
var $fen = $('#fen');
var $pgn = $('#pgn');

function onDragStart (source, piece, position, orientation) {
    // do not pick up pieces if the game is over
    if (game.game_over()) return false;

    // only pick up pieces for the side to move
    if ((game.turn() === 'w' && piece.search(/^b/) !== -1) ||
        (game.turn() === 'b' && piece.search(/^w/) !== -1)) {
        return false
    }
}

function onDrop (source, target) {
    // see if the move is legal
    var move = game.move({
        from: source,
        to: target,
        promotion: 'q' // NOTE: always promote to a queen for example simplicity
    });

    // illegal move
    if (move === null) return 'snapback';

    updateStatus()
}

// update the board position after the piece snap
// for castling, en passant, pawn promotion
function onSnapEnd () {
    board.position(game.fen())
}

function updateStatus () {
    var status = '';

    var moveColor = 'White';
    if (game.turn() === 'b') {
        moveColor = 'Black'
    }

    // checkmate?
    if (game.in_checkmate()) {
        status = 'Game over, ' + moveColor + ' is in checkmate.'
    }

    // draw?
    else if (game.in_draw()) {
        status = 'Game over, drawn position'
    }

    // game still on
    else {
        status = moveColor + ' to move';

        // check?
        if (game.in_check()) {
            status += ', ' + moveColor + ' is in check'
        }
    }

    $status.html(status);
    $fen.html(game.fen());
    $pgn.html(game.pgn({ max_width: 5, newline_char: '<br />' }))
}

var config = {
    draggable: true,
    position: 'start',
    onDragStart: onDragStart,
    onDrop: onDrop,
    onSnapEnd: onSnapEnd
};
board = Chessboard('myBoard', config);

updateStatus();
```

`.jsp` page

```
    <!doctype html>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/javascript/chessboardjs/css/chessboard-1.0.0.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>


<body>

<main>
    <div class="container">

        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            <h1>Hello World</h1>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm flex-row-reverse">Login</a>
        </div>

        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <i class="fas fa-chess-queen"></i>
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
                    aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button"
                           data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Dropdown
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                    <!-- Replace with Spring security Login form -->
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row justify-content-center mx-1 my-3">
                <div id="myBoard" class="col-6"></div>

                <div class="card bg-light col-3">
                    <div class="card-header">Header</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">PGN</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Here are the moves of the game as printed by test_game.js</p>
                        <div class="card-text" id="pgn"></div>
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary m-3">Reset Game</button>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <label>Status:</label>
                <div id="status"></div>

                <label>FEN:</label>
                <div id="fen"></div>
                <!--
                          <label>PGN:</label>
                          <div id="pgn"></div> -->
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</main>

<%-- jquery    --%>
<script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
        integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/javascript/chessboardjs/js/chessboard-1.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/javascript/node_modules/chess.js/chess.js"></script>
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/javascript/test_game.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

With `initgame.js`
[image: Results of initgame.js]
With `test_game.js`
[image: Results of test_game.js]
The results of the IntelliJ compare function
[image: IntelliJ confirms the files are identical]

Comment: OK, let's try to get the stupid question out of the way - did you clear your cache?

Comment: I thought this might be some caching issue. That's why I cleaned Maven and the artifacts and restarted IntelliJ. Is there a more direct way to clean the cache?

Comment: Clear the cache in your browser: Shift + Refresh/F5 for a hard refresh or directly go to the menu item that is for clearing history and delete all cache from there. For a test, you can just open a new browser you haven't used which wouldn't have the script cached.

Comment: VLAZ is on to something. The almost universal shortcut for clearing browser cache is CTRL-SHIFT-DEL, which brings up a dialog (for chrome, it's a new tab; for firefox, it's a daughter window) where you can clear cache, make sure it's for all time, etc)

Comment: You should compare not the source files in the project, but the files that are deployed on the server, you can find them in the location that you've configured as the artifact output directory: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/artifacts.html. That is the second thing to check after you eliminate the cache issue. The quick way to check it it's the cache it to open the page in the browser Incognito window.

Comment: Have you try "Invalidate Cache & Restart" in IntelliJ? From the File menu. I mean, no the cache from the Browser but from IntelliJ. Maybe it is still using the old JS

Comment: VLAZ Your solution worked. Thank you. I thought it was a IntelliJ caching issue not a browser caching issue. Shows what I know.

Answer (score 1):

try this : replace

```
$pgn.html(game.pgn({ max_width: 5, newline_char: '<br />' c}))
```

by

```
var pgnn = game.pgn({ max_width: 5, newline_char: '<br />' })
pgnn = pgnn + " </br>"
$pgn.html(pgnn)
```

i'm not sure that it gonna work but i think